# How to get substring value from main string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string similar to this one.

**HTML**

```
var str = "samplestring=:customerid and samplestring1=:dept";
```

**JS**

```
var parts = str.split(':');
var answer = parts;
```

I want to trim substrings which starts with colon`:` symbol from the main string

But it is returing the value like this

```
samplestring=,customerid and samplestring1=,dept
```

But I want it something like this.

```
customerid,dept
```

I am getting main string dynamically it may have colon more then 2.

I have created a fiddle also [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ryuwrwpr/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var str = "samplestring=:customerid and samplestring1=:dept";
alert(str.match(/:(\w+)/g).map(function(s){return s.substr(1)}).join(","))
```

Comment: @SrinivasPai, yes, I didn't use jQuery. I think, in this case it's better to add polyfill for map function if you need to support old IEs. Also you can find a fork of my answer with using of `$.map`.

Answer (score 3):

you can try regex:

```
var matches = str.match(/=:(\w+)/g); 
var answer = [];

if(matches){
    matches.forEach(function(s){
        answer.push(s.substr(2));
    });
}
```

Comment: This also worked But other answered worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner:

```
$.map(str.match(/:(\w+)/g), function(e, v) { return e.substr(1); }).join(",")
```

Comment: one small question why you want that $.map? I am not understanding use of that.

Comment: `$.map` is the [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function. It's a more explicit way of invoking the map function.

Comment: Why have you placed `?` in the regex?

Comment: And why do you think `$.map(a, f)` is _more explicit_ than `a.map(f)`?

Comment: @Qwertiy thanks for pointing out the `?`. I believe I was testing something. As for your other question, `$` is mapped to the `jQuery` object. So if you had to switch frameworks, albeit almost never worth it, it is easier to find usages of the framework (jQuery) by seeing what `$.___` are used.

Comment: `map` is a native browser function of array instanses. How is it related to changing the library (jQuery is not a framework)?

Comment: If you note the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it is not a well adopted till late. So, as a rule of thumb using a jQuery was a reliable way for browser compatibility. Maybe your point about jQuery not being a framework is that it is just a library, but I personally see it as a framework because it guides you to write code in a particular manner.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this

```
var str = "samplestring=:customerid and samplestring1=:dept and samplestring11=:dept";

var results = [];

var parts = str.split(' and ');
$.each(parts, function( key, value ) {
    results.push(value.split(':')[1]);
});
```

Now the `results` array contains the three values `customerid`, `dept`, and `dept`

Comment: What ever you have work only for the strings which have only 2 colons. if you have more then that it wont work. check this https://jsfiddle.net/ryuwrwpr/2/

Comment: @SrinivasPai Thanks for the heads up! I have edited the answer to make it generic. Hope it works for you! :)

Working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ryuwrwpr/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var str = "samplestring=:customerid and samplestring1=:dept";
var parts = str.split(':');
var dept = parts[2];
var cus_id = parts[1].split(' and ')[0];
alert(cus_id + ", " + dept );
```

Using this you will get o/p like :`customerid,dept`

Answer (score 1):

this will give you what you need...

```
var str = "samplestring=:customerid and samplestring1=:dept";
var parts = str.split(' and ');
var answer = [];
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  answer.push(parts[i].substring(parts[i].indexOf(':')+1));    
}

alert(answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "samplestring=:customerid and samplestring1=:dept";
alert(str.replace(/[^:]*:(\w+)/g, ",$1").substr(1))
```

Comment: This also worked But other answered worked perfectly.

Comment: @SrinivasPai, in fact, there is a case when this one fails. It doesn't handle the tail of the string.

Comment: Yes i checked never mind the other answered work. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here `\S` where `S` is capital is to get not space characters so it will get the word till first space match it, so it will match the word after `:` till the first space and we use `/g` to not only match the fisrt word and continue search in the string for other matches:

```
str.match(/:(\S*)/g).map(function(s){return s.substr(1)}).join(",")
```